# OctoberCMS 401, 402, 403, 503, 400 error code handling

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I just need to ask is octobercms has only capable of setting two types of errors ???

1. 404 [by creating a page with /404 url ]
2. 500 [by creating a page with /error url ]

how can we set 400, 401, 402, 403, 503, 400 etc ??????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those 2 are special cases where author already wrote code in `Cms Main Controller` but for others we need to write code on our own :)

Hmm all are related to `HttpException` so this are the codes actually we set and throw like this,

```
App::abort(403, 'Access is forbidden to the requested page.' /* message */);
```

Now these all are `HttpException`, We can intercept them using `App::error`. You need to add this code to your `plugin boot` method.

```
//\App::error(function(\Exception $exception) { // for handling all Exceptions

// for handling http related exceptions
\App::error(function(
    \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $exception) {

    dd($exception->getStatusCode()); /* 403 */ // 400, 401, 402, 403, 503, 400 etc            
    // Handle the exception...
});
```

You can check `status-code` here and handle them as you like.
Reference: https://octobercms.com/docs/services/error-log#http-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still has issues with passes status codes to the error page, simply add this to the `boot` method in `Plugin.php`

```
App::error(function(\Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException $exception) {
    $controller = new \Cms\Classes\Controller(\Cms\Classes\Theme::getActiveTheme());
    $controller->setStatusCode($exception->getStatusCode());
    return $controller->run('/error');
});
```

And check the status code on `/error` using

```
{% if this.controller.getStatusCode() == 403 %}
```